# Does for comprehension have something like "flatYield"?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I have some code like

```
//all data have different types
val data1Future = loadData1(params)
val data2Future = loadData2(params)
val data3Future = loadData3(params)

def saveResult(rez): Future[_] = ???

data1Future.flatMap { data1 =>
  data2Future.flatMap { data2 =>
    data3Future.flatMap { data3 =>
      //do some computation
      //several rows and several vals
      val rez = ???
      saveResult(rez)
   }
  }
}
```

But it is a litle bit ugly :) Unfortunatelly, I can't use for comprehension since I need something like "flatYield"

```
for {
  data1 <- data1Future
  data1 <- data1Future
  data1 <- data1Future
} flatYield {
  //do some computation
  //several rows and several vals
  val rez = data1 + data2 + data3
  saveResult(rez)
}
```

Do you know pattern that is such elegant as "for comprehension" but with flatMap instead of map at the end of the chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
for {
  data1 <- data1Future
  data2 <- data2Future
  data3 <- data3Future
  rez = {
    //do some computation
    //several rows and several vals
    data1 + data2 + data3
  }
  r <- saveResult(rez)
} yield r
```

This translates to

```
data1Future.flatMap { data1 =>
  data2Future.flatMap { data2 =>
    data3Future.flatMap { data3 =>
      val rez = {
        //do some computation
        //several rows and several vals
        data1 + data2 + data3
      }
      saveResult(rez).map(r => r)
    }
  }
}
```

which is isomorphic to your code.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you just want another line within your for-comprehension, and all of that "other computation" should go within another function to keep things clean:

```
for {
  data1 <- data1Future
  data2 <- data2Future
  data3 <- data3Future
  rez <- otherFunction(data1, data2, data3)
} yield rez 

def otherFunction(d1: ?, d2: ?, d3: ?): Future[?] = {
  //do some computation
  //several rows and several vals
}
```

Alternatively you can use something like this:

```
(for {
  data1 <- data1Future
  data2 <- data2Future
  data3 <- data3Future
} yield {
  (data1, data2, data3)
}) flatMap { case (data1, data2, data3) =>
  //do some computation
  //several rows and several vals
  saveResult(rez)
}
```

Comment: The signature is wrong on otherFunction.  data[1-3] are values extracted from futures so d[1-3] will have whatever OP's types are.

Comment: Sorry, I voted for other answer and want to explain why. Your first solution need meaningless separate function, second one require to name same data three times.

Comment: @user3067313 Another function is not "meaningless". It breaks up the code into logical pieces, which makes it easier to unit test and read. What is easier to test: four simple functions with clear input/output and edge cases, or one huge function where four times as many things can go wrong, and it isn't clear method caused the breakage?

Comment: @m-z completely agree with you in general, but especially this example assume just several lines of processing code, and all code is already wrapped into function. So I don't see reason to have "calculateSomething" and "calculateSomethingInternal" just to use for comprehension. And also, in that case I need to name same data twice.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for comprehension (like your stated goal) is equivalent to the defining the futures in a sequence of flatMap operations will wait for the result of each future before going to the next.  Since your futures don't depend on each other you can start them all without waiting for the previous one to complete - this is what you have done in your initial example.

Start them concurrently and store the futures in a sequence use Future.sequence to turn the collection of futures into a single Future that won't complete until ALL of them complete (or any one of them fails).  Then save your result when the future Completes.

```
val data1Future = loadData1(params) //type = Future[foo]
val data2Future = loadData2(params)
val data3Future = loadData3(params)

val listOfFutures = List(data1Future,data2Future,data3Future) //type = List[Future[foo]]

val futureOfList = Future.sequence(listOfFutures)  //type = Future[List[foo]]

futureOfList.onComplete( list => saveResult(list.reduce(_ + _))
```

Comment: While your first sentence is true, the `Future`s in the OP's example *do* execute at the same time, because `loadData1(params)` returning `Future` is called *before* `flatMap`. They would only execute in sequence if `loadData1(params)`, etc were called within the for-comprehension.

Comment: Yes but not in the for comprehension as in the OP's example of what they are trying to do.  I've updated my response.

Comment: 1. dataN have different types, so they can't be merged in regular collection
2. + is just example operation, sorry for inaccuracy. There can be several row of processing code

Comment: @Gangstead The OP's `Future`s are already running in parallel, but thanks for the rage downvote (Pardon if it wasn't you, but I didn't even downvote your answer, it's still a valid approach). The `flatMap` waits for the first `Future` to complete to execute, but that does **not** prevent the next `Future` from starting, as it started before the for-comprehension. The for-comprehension will still only take as long as the slowest `Future`.

Comment: Furthermore, `Future.sequence` just calls `flatMap` internally anyway when folding the `List[Future[A]]`, so it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: Sorry OP I should have gotten clarification on that. I assumed same type based on your example and my response very much relies on that.  @m-z your comment had a mistake in it.  I clarified and clarified again that the way the OP defines the futures in the first part of their example are running in parallel, but not in the second part of their example.  My wording still sucks.  My solution was what OP asked for: an elegant option, but it assumed futures of same type so they could go in a collection.  I didn't say it doesn't work with flatmaps