# Does Scala have anything like a flatYield?

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

A similar question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913693/does-for-comprehension-have-something-like-flatyield), but some of the responses don't fully acknowledge how to run the original, "independent" `Future`s asynchronously (rather than in chained `flatMap`s or for-comprehension).  I'm also curious about the case with more than one chained `Future`s that are all "dependent" on the original `Future`s but not on each other.

Anyway, here's what I'm doing:

```
val f0 = Future { foo() }
val f1 = Future { bar() }
val f01 = for { v0 <- f0; v1 <- f1 } yield (v0, v1)
f01.flatMap { case (v0, v1) =>
  val f2 = Future { baz(v0, v1) }
  val f3 = Future { qux(v0, v1) }
  for { v2 <- f2; v3 <- f3 } yield (v2, v3)
}
```

And here's what I'd like to do:

```
val f0 = Future { foo() }
val f1 = Future { bar() }
for { v0 <- f0; v1 <- f1 } flatYield {
  val f2 = Future { baz(v0, v1) }
  val f3 = Future { qux(v0, v1) }
  for { v2 <- f2; v3 <- f3 } yield (v2, v3)
}
```

Is there any way to do this without yielding the original values first and then writing them all out again in the chained `flatMap`'s arguments?

Comment: OK, someone fill me in. Why not `for {v0<-f0; v1<-f1} yield (baz(v0,v1), qux(v0,v1))`?

Comment: @jwvh In your example `baz` and `qux` will be run sequentially (not in parallel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work for you?

```
val f0 = Future { foo() }
val f1 = Future { bar() }
for { 
  v0 <- f0
  v1 <- f1 
  f2 = Future { baz(v0, v1)}
  f3 = Future { qux(v0, v1)}
  v2 <- f2
  v3 <- f3
} yield (v2, v3)
```

Comment: Wow, yes, works perfectly.  Makes for much cleaner code.  Thank you!

Comment: doesn't that mean that f2 and f3 can't run in parallel?

Comment: You can even move f0 and f1 into the for-comprehension, if you read this: http://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-protips-2.html

Comment: Very helpful--I had been making that "common mistake" early on.  And I've actually already started doing what your post suggests--starting for-expressions off with a `Future.successful {}`.  It's nice to know that there's at least a little bit of precedent for it.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to simplify the code a bit is to use the `zip` method of `Future`:

```
for { 
  (v0, v1) <- Future { foo() } zip Future { bar() }
  r <- Future { baz(v0, v1) } zip Future { qux(v0, v1) }
} yield r
```

For more `Future`s instead of multiple `zip`s you can also use `Future.sequence`:

```
for {
  List(a, b, c, d) <- Future.sequence(List(
    Future { foo1() }, 
    Future { foo2() }, 
    Future { foo3() }, 
    Future { foo4() }
  ))
  /* ... */
} yield ???
```

In both cases zipped/sequenced futures will be executed in parallel (depending on the `ExecutionContext` of course).